# Update Timestamp field Spring JPA within Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How can I set FROZEN_DATE with current time when updating frozen state while using @Query annotation.
If I update fields other than frozen frozen_state will not be updated.

```
@Repository
public interface UserEntryRepository extends CrudRepository <UserEntry, String> {

   UserEntry findByUsername(String username);

   @Transactional
   @Modifying
   @Query("UPDATE UserEntry o SET o.frozen = 1 WHERE o.username = :username")
   int setFrozenForOfuser(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

**Entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFUSER", schema = "TIMS")
public class UserEntry implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 546720609517412501L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
   private String username;

   @Column(name = "FROZEN")
   private Integer frozen;

   @Column(name = "FROZEN_DATE")
   private Date frozendate;


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CURRENT_DATE` like this :

```
UPDATE UserEntry o SET o.frozen = 1, o.frozen = CURRENT_DATE WHERE o.username = :username
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, as there is probably no "best" solution for this. I personally would introduce a `boolean dirtyFrozen` flag, that gets set to `true` whenever the `frozen` property is being updated. This can be implemented in the `void setFrozen(boolean frozen)` method.

Then you can introduce the following into your entity, which will be called before each database update:

```
@PreUpdate
private void onUpdate() {
    if (this.dirtyFrozen) {
        this.frozen = now();
    }
}
```

As I said, this is just my personal approach. There might be dozens of other solutions that could be cleaner or prettier.

Hope I was able to help!